# Spatial Basis Functions...any practical hints on choosing them?

Tags: functions, approximation, diophantine-approximation

I am not coming from a pure mathematical background, and now in my daily life as an engineering student, I am getting faced to [spatial basis functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basis_function)  to approximates variables. The problem is: Are there any real practical hints on how best can we choose these functions?

Comment: In general, the choice depends on the specific problem you're facing with.

Comment: are there any hints to start with?

Comment: have you ever faced with finite element methods?

Comment: @the_candyman  yes, this is actually what I am facing, but whith models differing in dimension, that is to say, I deal with models ranging from $1D$ up to $3D$

Comment: I think that the best approximating basis functions that one can use at the very beginning are linear polynomials over segments (1D) or triangles (2D) elements. Never faced with 3D problems.